# Remove key from nested python dictionary via list of keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary, i.e.

```
a={'k1':{'k2':1}}
```

I would like to write a function

```
def f(dictionary,key_list):
      pass
```

such that `f(a,['k1','k2']`) would be equivalent to `del(a['k1']['k2'])`

I tried to use

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def f(dictionary,key_list):
     reduce(operator.delitem,key_list,dictionary)
```

However

```
f(a,['k1','k2'])
```

returns

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item deletion
```

Comment: `operator.delitem` returns `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only want to delete from the innermost dictionary, not from the outer dictionaries. So for the path to get to the innermost dictionary you need to use `getitem`, not `delitem`. Only the last key should be used for deletion:

```
def f(dictionary, key_list):
    *path, key = key_list
    del reduce(operator.getitem, path, dictionary)[key]
```

Demo (with one more level to be clearer):

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def f(dictionary, key_list):
    *path, key = key_list
    del reduce(operator.getitem, path, dictionary)[key]

a = {'k1': {'k2': {'k3': 1}}}
f(a, ['k1', 'k2', 'k3'])
print(a)
```

That prints `{'k1': {'k2': {}}}`, same as after `del a['k1']['k2']['k3']`:

```
a = {'k1': {'k2': {'k3': 1}}}
del a['k1']['k2']['k3']
print(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would `reduce` on `dict.get` over all but the last key to find the inner-most dictionary, then invoke `del` on that `dict` using the final key.

```
def f(dictionary,key_list):
    dictionary = reduce(dict.get, key_list[0:-1], dictionary)
    del dictionary[key_list[-1]]


a={'k1':{'k2':1}}
print(a)
f(a,['k1','k2'])
print(a)
```

Result:

```
$ python x.py 
{'k1': {'k2': 1}}
{'k1': {}}
```